# displaying json_encode results individually

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Hi I was able to display a json data(List of conversation result) but I want to display them just like how I display records from database like this:

```
   foreach(res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as result):
    $username = $result['username'];
    $message = $result['message'];
    endforeach;
```

are there any similar procedure like this but with `json_encode()` ?

here is my php script

```
$sql6="SELECT msgid FROM thread WHERE combination1=:msgids OR combination2=:submsgids LIMIT 1";
        $msg_id = $con4->prepare($sql6);
        $msg_id->bindParam(':msgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $msg_id->bindParam(':submsgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $msg_id->execute();
        $msgd = $msg_id->fetchColumn();
        $tbpre = $msgd;
        $sql7 = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbpre."chat_conversation WHERE msgid=:chat";

        $stmt7=$con3->prepare($sql7);
        $stmt7->bindValue( 'chat', $msgd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt7->execute();
        $rows = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode($rows);
```

This php script are getting its data from my ajax script below

```
        function AjaxRetrieve()
            {
              var rid = document.getElementById('trg').value,
            data = {chat: uid, rid: rid, name: user};
 $.ajax({
      url: "includes/getChat.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
 success: function(result){
        var container = $("#clog");

        $.each(result, function(i, message) {
            $.each(message, function(key, value) {
                container.append($('<p />').html(key + ':' + value));
            });
        });
   }
});
```

The php and javascript are working fine the JSON are being displayed.. But I'm trying to figure out if there is a way that I can display only the username and the message just how I use the `foreach` statement that I mentioned above...

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding, but you should be able to filter what is displayed by adding a condition with an `if`

```
$.each(result, function(i, message) {
    $.each(message, function(key, value) {
        if (key == "username" || key == "message")
            container.append($('<p />').html(key + ':' + value));
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi.. I've tried your code and I was able to display the username only but not the message what should I replace `||` for the message to appear with the username?.. is `||` also known as `OR` on javascript btw? I'm quite a noob on javascript sorry if its kinda annoying..